# Trace a recursive coin change algorithm

Tags: algorithm, recursion, trace, coin-change

I am trying to trace this recursive algorithm of the coin change problem with M=10, c={5,3,1} and d=3. M is the value of money for which change is required, c is the different coin values available and d is the number of different coin values available. I am confused as to how to trace it.

**RecursiveChange(M,c,d)**

```
if M = 0
    return 0
bestNumCoins <- infinity
for i -> 1 to d
    if M ≥ c(i)
        numCoins <- RecursiveChange(M – c(i) , c, d)
        if numCoins + 1 < bestNumCoins
            bestNumCoins <- numCoins + 1
    return bestNumCoins
```

Call 1: RecursiveChange(10, {5, 3, 1}, 3)

Call 2: RecursiveChange(5, {5, 3, 1}, 3)

Call 3: RecursiveChange(0, {5, 3, 1}, 3)

In call 3, 0 will be returned since M=0. What I understand: 0 is returned to call 2. Then, continuing from call 2, the following part is run:

```
if numCoins + 1 < bestNumCoins
                bestNumCoins <- numCoins + 1
        return bestNumCoins
```

where bestNumCoins will take the value of 1. This value of 1 is then returned to call 1. Then, continuing from call 1, since numCoins + 1 (i.e. 2) is not < bestNumCoins (i.e. 1), bestNumCoins will remain 1, and this value of 1 will then be the final value. First of all, I think 2 should be the final value here because to get 10 units, two coins of value 5 are needed.

I need help to figure it out, please. I've been spending hours on it.

Answer (score 0):

`bestNumCoins` is meant to be a local variable, meaning that each call to the function has its own separate value for `bestNumCoins`.

Although in call #2 `bestNumCoins` was set to 1, in call #1 its value still remains infinity. After the call to #2 returns with the value 1, `bestNumCoins` in call #1 will change to the value 2 (the returned value plus 1).